# UNION ALL Query for tables that don't match

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using the following query to display dynamic pages, where the page URL's are values stored in two database tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM gw_geog WHERE URL = :MyURL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM gw_world_urls WHERE URL = :MyURL
) AS X";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

I'm going to wind up with four or five tables holding more detailed information. I'd like to write separate queries for each table, as each one is a little different. But I first need an intermediate query to get a little information.

So I tried to transform the following query into another UNION ALL query, but it isn't working.

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT GG.N, GG.IDArea MyID, GG.URL, GG.IDParent
 FROM gw_geog GG
 WHERE GG.URL LIKE :XURL");
$stm->execute(array(
'XURL'=>$XURL
));
```

Can anyone tell me how to use UNION ALL to query three tables named gw_geog, gw_geog_regions and gw_geog_landforms, where each has fields named URL and IDParent, but only gw_geog has a field named IDArea?

Here's what I'd like to do:

1) Get each country's ID (IDArea) and parent (IDParent) from table gw_geog. (I don't need ID's or parents for the other queries.)

2) Give each row a value based on its source table. For example, the row that includes the value 'russia' is stored in the table gw_geog. So I'd like it to have a value like $Type = 'country.' The rows with the values 'midwest' and 'amazon-river' come from the tables gw_geog_regions and gw_geog_landforms. So I'd like every row from gw_geog_regions to have the value $Type = 'region' and every row from gw_geog_landforms to be $Type = 'landform'.

If I can get a "Type" (e.g. country, region or landform) for each row, it will help me create a query targeting that category. ID's and parents will also help put together a query for countries and states (table gw_geog).

**UPDATE**

I've been playing with my new query, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've modified my tables a bit, so there a few changes. But it doesn't display any values for $IDParent or $Type X, nor does print_r($row) display anything. Can anyone see what I did wrong?

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, 'country' AS TypeX FROM gw_geog
 UNION ALL
 SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, 'region' AS TypeX FROM gw_geog_regions
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, 'landform' AS TypeX FROM gw_geog_landforms
) AS Combined
WHERE Combined.URL LIKE :XURL");
$stm->execute(array(
'XURL'=>$XURL
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $IDParent = $row['IDParent'];
 $TypeX = $row['TypeX'];  
 print_r($row);
}
print_r($row);
echo $TypeX;
echo $IDParent;
```

Comment: For the first query, why not just run two queries and sum the results in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of adding a static `Type` for each is a good idea. It merely needs to be done with single-quoted string literals like

```
SELECT 'region' AS Type
```

in the `SELECT` list.

To use the tables lacking `IDArea`, query for `NULL` in place of that column in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT NULL AS IDArea
```

It is possible to fill out a `UNION` query between mismatched tables using combinations of `NULL`s or string literals to ensure the columns all align.

So your full query would look like

```
/* Literal string (single-quoted) 'country','region','landform' aliased as `Type` */
SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, 'country' AS Type FROM gw_geog
UNION ALL
/* NULL in place of IDArea */
SELECT URL, NULL AS IDArea, IDParent, 'region' AS Type FROM gw_geog_regions
UNION ALL 
/* NULL in place of IDArea */
SELECT URL NULL AS IDArea, IDParent, 'landform' AS Type FROM gw_geog_landforms
```

Applying the `WHERE` clause can be done on the outside if you enclose it all as a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT URL, IDArea, IDParent, 'country' AS Type FROM gw_geog
    UNION ALL
    SELECT URL, NULL AS IDArea, IDParent, 'region' AS Type FROM gw_geog_regions
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT URL NULL AS IDArea, IDParent, 'landform' AS Type FROM gw_geog_landforms
) AS combined
WHERE combined.URL LIKE :XURL
```

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski - Awesome; you also answered a second question I asked when I updated my post. One question, though - I created the new query, and after the query I typed in echo $Type. But I get an Undefined Variable error message. Do I have to define $Type in my while loop? Normally, I'd put something like $Type = row['Type'] but I don't know how to write it for this compound query.

Comment: Yes, you would need to get it with `$Type = $row['Type']` (or similar) in your `while` fetch loop.  Even though we added it and it wasn't a real column, as far as the query output is concerned it behaves exactly the same as a real table column.

Comment: If you `print_r($row)` inside your fetch loop, you should see it there.

Comment: Hmmm...$Type = $row['Type'] doesn't work, and print_r($row) doesn't display anything. I'll play with it for a while; maybe I just did something wrong. Thx.

Comment: Test it first in a MySQL client, out of context of your PHP code to ensure you're getting the result you expect. Then figure out how to fetch from it.

Comment: OK, I tested it in phyMyAdmin and found my mistake. It works great now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The textbook answer is to select A, B, C from the tables that have those columns and select A, B, NULL from the tables that are missing one. Considering making a view that implements the union so you can keep the business logic simple.